# Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$~$N(0,1)$.  Define the random variable $X_c$ as $X$ if $|X| \le c$ and $0$ otherwise.  I am trying to figure out the density function of $X_c$ to calculate $E(X_c)$ and $Var(X_c)$.  Outside of $-c$ and $c$ the density function should be 0.  Between $-c$ and $0$ and then between $0$ and $c$, the density function should be the same as $X$'s density function.  However, I can't figure out how to handle it at 0.  Do I need a dirac delta or something similar.  I don't have much experience with discontinuous density and distribution functions.  Finally, is the the variance stated in this wiki article correct here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution ?  I tried calculating variance using conditioning and got their answer times $P(-c\le x\le c)^2$.  That is when I started looking back at the density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote a continuous random variable with density $f_X$ and $X_c=X\mathbf 1_{|X|\leqslant c}$ for some $c\geqslant0$. The distribution of $X_c$ has a Dirac part at $0$ with mass $p_c=P[|X|\gt c]$ and a densitable part with density $g_c$ defined by $g_c(x)=f_X(x)\mathbf 1_{|x|\leqslant c}$ for every $x$.

Note that $\displaystyle p_c+\int_\mathbb Rg_c=p_c+\int_{-c}^cf_X=P[|X|\gt c]+P[|X|\leqslant c]=1$, as it should.
Furthermore, for every measurable function $u$ such that $u(X_c)$ is integrable, $\displaystyle E[u(X_c)]=p_cu(0)+\int_{-c}^cu(x)f_X(x)\mathrm dx$. Thus, for every positive integer $n$,
$$
E[X_c^n]=\int_{-c}^cx^nf_X(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
When $X$ is symmetric (for example $X$ centered normal), $E[X_c]=0$ and
$$
\mathrm{var}(X_c)=\int_{-c}^cx^2f_X(x)\mathrm dx=E[X^2;|X|\leqslant c].
$$
A different object is the distribution of $X$ *conditioned by* $|X|\leqslant c$. A random variable $Y_c$ follows this distribution if and only if, for every $u$ such that the RHS exists,
$$
E[u(Y_c)]=E[u(X)\mid |X|\leqslant c].
$$
Then,
$$
E[u(Y_c)]=\frac{E[u(X); |X|\leqslant c]}{P[|X|\leqslant c]},
$$
hence, if $u(0)=0$,
$$
E[u(Y_c)]=\frac{E[u(X_c)]}{P[|X|\leqslant c]},
$$
for example,
$$
\mathrm{var}(Y_c)=\frac{\mathrm{var}(X_c)}{P[|X|\leqslant c]}.
$$

Comment: So the "truncated" r.v. I describe and the one in the wikipedia article are two different r.v.s aren't they?

Comment: Yes. (And this makes for a shorter answer... :-))

Answer (score 0):

The variance in the Wikipedia article is correct; however, your analysis elides an important distinction.

If $X$ is normally distributed, then let $f(x)$ be its probability density function. Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx = 1$, by definition of a probability density function.

It follows that since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, then $\int_{-c}^c f(x)\ dx < \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx$ for all finite $c$.

Therefore, the distribution function for $X_c$ you have described does *not* yield a probability distribution function.

As a consequence, you must transform $x \mapsto kx$ in the description of $X_c$'s distribution function by some $k$ such that $\int_{-c}^c f(kx)\ d(kx) = 1$. Computing your variance, etc. from here should address those errors.

Comment: It seems the way you describe raises the density everywhere when in reality the density is only different from the standard normal at $0$.

Comment: @LeoSpencer That's incorrect. The function is continuous at zero.

Comment: Why how would I know that?

Comment: Is it possible to have a point mass at 0 where the probability of there is non-zero as opposed to most density function where the probability of a point is 0.

Comment: That's not at all what your random variable $X_c$ describes.

Comment: There's an important distinction here that you're maybe missing. The PDF of $X$ is a bell curve, and at every point $x$ it describes the probability that the random variable $X$ is at most some value $x$. If you chop this curve off at $\pm c$, you no longer get a probability density function, you simply get a transformation of a random variable. $${}{}$$

In other words, the pdf of $X^2$ is not necessarily $f^2(x)$. You're transforming the random variable, so you have to condition the variable $x$ to adequately describe its probability density.

Comment: But isn't $P(X_c=0) = P(|X|>c) = 2\int^{\infty}_c f(x)dx$ where f is the standard normal density?

Comment: Think about it like this. For $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, the probability that $X \le -1$ is non-zero. But if you set $c = 1$, then the probability that $X_c \le -1$ is exactly zero.

Comment: @LeoSpencer No, that's not correct at all.

Comment: What is wrong with the logic in my last post?

Comment: Please see @did answer and comment there whether you disagree or if that is what you were saying.

Comment: Are you sure that this is precisely how you are given the definition of $X_c$? Because what you have described is not the truncated normal distribution.

Comment: @LeoSpencer There is a communication error somewhere. Your title says "Truncated Normal distribution", but your definition of $X_c$ definitely does not yield the truncated normal distribution. The difference is that the truncated normal distribution has compact support (in one variable), but your definition of $X_c$ does not. I suspect that there is a wording error, because if you were expected to perform an analysis such as did's, then you would surely note that $X_c$ as described is not truncated normal. My comments refer specifically to the truncated normal case only.

Comment: Yes.  So we were actually talking about two different r.v.s correct?

Comment: Yes, but I urge caution, because describing the actual truncated normal distribution with words would be done in almost exactly the same way you described $X_c$. Are you certain that's not what you want?

Comment: No my professor has used this $X_c$ several times.  Thanks for the discussion though.